# Will my current UK Tier 2 sponsor be notified if I try applying for another Tier 2 visa using a certificate of sponsorship from another employer?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

More information:
Currently on a UK Tier 2 sponsored visa that is being sponsored by my current employer. I just got an offer from another company that is willing to sponsor my Tier 2 visa. I will like to know if the UKBA will notify my current sponsor if I try applying for a new Tier 2 visa using the new Certificate of Sponsorship that the new company will issue to me.

Comment: Considering the strength of the Data Protection laws in the UK, I seriously doubt it. Heck, you would be lucky if *you* could find out what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

The current employer will not be notified. The caseworker will check BOTH employers in the SMS.  If your T2 is an ICT, you will not get a relaxation on any applicable cooling-off periods.

People use a new CoS to change jobs all the time, there is nothing particularly unusual about it.